# Right way to set GTK3 widget colours to a computed value

Tags: haskell, gtk3

In my user interface (coded in Haskell) I want to set some widget background and foreground colours to values computed by the application (as opposed to a theme colour). I initially used [`widgetOverrideBackgroundColor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk-3.0.31/docs/GI-Gtk-Objects-Widget.html#g:172) and `widgetOverrideColor` for this, despite the fact that they are deprecated. However these have recently stopped working (fair enough, they are deprecated).

What is the easiest way to get the functionality of `widgetOverrideColor` and its relatives? Is there a way of programmatically generating a style provider for a single widget and setting the colours there (the widgets are also generated dynamically)? Or is the solution to intercept the `draw` callback? If so, how can I set the colours and then hand back control to the original?

Answer (score 1):

I've now managed to do this using a combination of CSS and intercepted `draw` signals. The code is in Haskell as its what I'm writing in, but it should be translatable to other languages.

The basic technique is to add some extra Cairo code to the `draw` callback to paint a different background, and then use CSS to set make the widget itself transparent. This code uses the [gi-gtk](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk) library for GTK3, the [cairo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo) library for drawing, and the [colour](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/colour) library for colours. This has been extracted and slightly simplified from a larger program. I hope I haven't left anything dangling.

```
import qualified GI.Cairo.Structs.Context as Gtk
import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.Cairo as Cairo
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.Cairo.Internal as CI
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.Cairo.Types as Cairo (Cairo (Cairo))

import qualified Data.Colour as C
import qualified Data.Colour.CIE as C
import qualified Data.Colour.SRGB as C

customPaint :: (Gtk.isWidget w) => w -> Maybe Colour -> Gtk.Context -> IO ()

customPaint widget Nothing _ = do
     -- No background, so reset everything.
     style <- Gtk.widgetGetStyleContext widget
     mapM_ (Gtk.styleContextRemoveClass style) [lightClass, darkClass]

customPaint widget (Just c) ctx = do
     -- Get the dimensions of the background.
     w <- Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedWidth widget
     h <- Gtk.widgetGetAllocatedHeight widget
     -- Set the widget style to transparent using a class.
     style <- Gtk.widgetGetStyleContext widget
     mapM_ (Gtk.styleContextRemoveClass style) [lightClass, darkClass]
     Gtk.styleContextAddClass style $ if C.luminance c > 0.5 then lightClass else darkClass
     -- Draw the background using the Cairo Render monad.
     runRender ctx $ do
        let
           C.RGB r1 g1 b1 = C.toSRGB c
        Cairo.setSourceRGB r1 g1 b1
        Cairo.rectangle 0 0 (fromIntegral w) (fromIntegral h)
        Cairo.fill

  -- Conversion between gi-gtk Cairo Context and Cario library Render monad. Only
  -- needed because they have different ways of wrapping the underlying C object.
  runRender ctx action =
     Gtk.withManagedPtr ctx $ \p ->
        runReaderT (CI.runRender action) (Cairo.Cairo (castPtr p))

  -- CSS class names. "light" uses black text on a pale background. "dark" is the opposite.
  lightClass = "transparent-light"
  darkClass = "transparent-dark"
```

Then you can store the colour you want in an IORef and create a callback for the widget drawing signal like this:

```
Gtk.onWidgetDraw myWidget $ \ctx -> do
   c <- readIORef colourRef
   customPaint myWidget c ctx
```

The CSS for the application contains the following:

```
/* Custom CSS classes for coloured widgets.

The background is transparent. The foreground is either black or white.
*/
.hades-transparent-dark {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent; }

.hades-transparent-light {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent; }
```

Luckily I only need to set the background colour, with the foreground colour being either black or white for contrast with the background. I don't know how I would go about setting an arbitrary foreground colour.

Answer (score 0):

The [GTK documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-background-color) recommends using CSS:

> `gtk_widget_override_background_color` has been deprecated since version 3.16 and should not be used in newly-written code.
>
> This function is not useful in the context of CSS-based rendering. If you wish to change the way a widget renders its background you should use a custom CSS style, through an application-specific GtkStyleProvider and a CSS style class. You can also override the default drawing of a widget through the “draw” signal, and use Cairo to draw a specific color, regardless of the CSS style.

For reference, in [my own GTK3 application](https://github.com/bradrn/cabasa/tree/853f1de4a323cf50fd47a6a7368dc94d9786d871) I used the following code to load custom CSS:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import GI.Gtk

main = do
    -- stuff
    prov <- cssProviderNew
    cssProviderLoadFromPath prov "path/to/custom/css/file.css"
    screenGetDefault >>= \case
        Just screen -> styleContextAddProviderForScreen screen prov 800
        Nothing -> return ()
```

For the CSS file itself, you can refer to widgets by their [names](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-name). The following CSS is untested, but should work:

```css
#widgetname1 {
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
}
```

I don’t know if there is a way of doing this purely programatically, without any external CSS files (i.e. specifying the CSS inline); if I find a method I will update this answer.

Comment: I could use an external file if there was just a way of having the program change the colours on the fly. I'm also generating the widgets under application control (they reflect a user-specified data structure), so I'd need each widget to have its own individual CSS overriding the standard theme.

Comment: @PaulJohnson If I’m understanding your question correctly, you want to know if you can still use external CSS to modify individual widgets when they’re generated by Haskell code? That should be fine — just give each widget a name using `widgetSetName` (I think) and then refer to them as `#name1`, `#name2` etc in the CSS. (If that wasn’t your question, feel free to correct me.)

Comment: @bradm: no, I also want to set arbitrary background colours under program control. See my answer below.

Comment: @PaulJohnson That’s certainly an ingenious way of solving this! It’s just a pity there doesn’t seem to be an easier way to do this…

Comment: The real pity is that there used to be a way, but it got deleted. http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/fascist.html

Comment: @PaulJohnson Of course — you’re obviously thinking more clearly than I am. (By the way, when enough time has passed, can you accept your own answer?)